# Look up tables, Flash or SRAM?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, flash, ram, stm32f4

A STM32F4 platform is used, which has 192kBytes SRAM, which is sufficient for me.

I am trying to build a look up table. The LUT will be used in calculation several times. And I want to put it in SRAM in the process of calculation, instead of FLASH, since reading SRAM is faster than reading FLASH for the core.

And I read this post mentioning putting the LUT in flash, which confuses me.. What should I do to burn the data into flash for the first load and the data will be kept in RAM afterwards for following calculations?

And if anyone knows CCM, is it a good idea to put the LUT in CCM during computation?

Comment: How big is the LUT?

Comment: How would the size matter? In my application, only 32 float numbers.

Comment: Presumably (**IANA embedded systems developer**) if the Core Coupled Memory capacity is underutilized, placing the LUT there will avoid any contention and provide predictable timing. Copying the LUT from the main SRAM to CCM at each use might be useful if other components will be actively using SRAM concurrently and the number of lookups is reasonably large (e.g., if only half the SRAM bus cycles are available to the core, copying 32 values might add 80 cycles [1.5 to load from SRAM, 1 to store to CCM], making 160 lookups break-even at 1.5 cycles each for SRAM vs. 1 each for CCM).

Comment: Apart from the cost trade-off of SRAM vs Flash, there is also a small cache for the larger STM32 devices (as opposed to, say, the AVR).  Therefore, SRAM access time is not completely predictable - it will depend if the LUT currently resides in cache, or if it needs to be fetched from SRAM first into cache.

Comment: @Damien The cache is for instructions not for data I think, which is used together with ART for stm32F407. Could you check on that?

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Is it possible to load data from Flash to CCM in boot directly, not through SRAM? And run-time performance is more important, load from SRAM to CCM can be considered as initialize.

Comment: [Datasheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00037051.pdf): "RAM memory is accessed (read/write) at CPU clock speed with 0 wait states."

Comment: [Datasheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00037051.pdf): "To release the processor full 210 DMIPS performance at this frequency, the accelerator
implements an instruction prefetch queue and branch cache, which increases program execution speed from the 128-bit Flash memory."

Comment: So, my conclusion: if you need to fetch something from a LUT stored only in flash, and that part of the LUT is not currently in cache, then you'll almost certainly get a processor stall, because it hasn't been pre-fetched by the ART accelerator.  This very strongly favours having the LUT in SRAM, assuming (of course) there is sufficient room.

Comment: I agree with you Damien. Just one comment, the LUT cannot be loaded by cache I think. Cache is only for instructions, not data..

Comment: If cache is indeed only for instructions, then we'll have no choice but to cop the bus wait cycles for the LUT to be fetched from flash.  This could leave the CPU doing not much for a while, depending on how fast the flash is (and who else wants to access the bus).

Comment: Can we just load the LUT from flash to SRAM and every time a computation is performed, the data will be red from SRAM directly?

Comment: @Damien Is the 0 wait state for RAM under the condition of no contention from other accesses (i.e., 1 cycle latency)? Otherwise it would have to be dual ported or always give the core priority and possibly starve other users (e.g., DMA). [This blog post](http://sigalrm.blogspot.com/2013/12/using-ccm-memory-on-stm32.html) seems to indicate that contention is an issue and a reason for using CCM.

Comment: @richieqianle  If the LUT is small, try to have it *resident* in SRAM, or better yet, CCM.  This will avoid stalls in the process of loading it from flash to SRAM.  See also the answer below.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton, I'd summarise that blog post as an answer and provide some context. It answers everything in the OP.

Comment: @Damien Well, then do so.

Answer (score 5):

Simply defining the table *without* a const keyword will cause the table to be copied from Flash to RAM when your program starts up; e.g.

```
const short ax [] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };      // stays in Flash
short bx [] = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };            // starts in Flash, copied to RAM
```

You can verify this behavior with the following two lines of code:

```
bx[0] = ax[0];    // allowed, since you are modifying a RAM variable
ax[0] = bx[0];    // not allowed, ax is const
```

I checked this out using the IAR compiler for the STM32F10 family.  I don't know what CCM is, sorry.

It's not uncommon for embedded programmers to define a large initialized table, forgetting the const keyword, and then wonder why they are running out of RAM.

Comment: CCM is Core Coupled Memory. "This tight coupling of the CCM memory to the core, leads to zero wait states, in other words, the core has exclusive access to this memory block, so for example, while other bus masters are using the main SRAM the core can access the CCM." ([source](http://sigalrm.blogspot.com/2013/12/using-ccm-memory-on-stm32.html))

Comment: The keyword "const" does not *guarantee* that the data will be in SRAM only - the behaviour will be compiler-specific. See, for example, [avr-libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/pgmspace.html).

Comment: Note also to C++ users: regarding const-ness. A [const_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) will remove the const keyword, so if you are relying on the "const" keyword to embed data in flash, be careful of this behaviour.